# Unity Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) is not working

Tags: unity, unityscript

My code to detect left mouse click is not working **Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) and Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)**.
But same code for **Input.GetMouseButton(0)** is working.

Code:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
  #if UNITY_ANDROID
    mouseWorldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition + new Vector3(0, 0, 4f));
    mouseCameraOffset = bowlingBall.position - mouseWorldPos;

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Debug.Log("last");
        lastMousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    }
```

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin the question that you've suggested is about continuous mouse button press but I want only once the button is pressed or not and this function **Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)** is appropriate but it's not working .

Comment: You are right. That question is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Mouse events might be fired and lost between two consecutive `FixedUpdate`s.

Use `Update` to make sure you capture all of them.