# Issue with Jumping

Tags: unity, c#, 3d

In my game, you have to press (or more accurately release) space bar to jump. However, at seemingly random instances the player wouldn't jump. So it is working fine most of the times but then out of nowhere, the cube doesn't jump even when input is given. Please help!

```
    public float horizontalSpeed = 0.5f;
    Rigidbody rb;
    public float JumpHeight = 10f;
    private bool onGround;
    public float forwardSpeed;
    public float rotSpeed;


    private float increaseJumpBy = 1f;
    private bool increaseJumpHeight;
    private bool jumped = false;

    public SimpleHealthBar healthBar;

    private float Horizontal;
    private float Forward;
    Vector3 forwardMovement;
    Quaternion verRotation;
    Vector3 horizontalmovement;

    public float maxJump;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        onGround = true;
        Forward = Time.deltaTime * forwardSpeed;
        forwardMovement = new Vector3(0f, 0f, Forward);
        verRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);           
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + forwardMovement);

        Jump();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        healthBar.UpdateBar(JumpHeight, maxJump);   
    }

    void Jump()
    {
      //Debug.Log("Jumpheight" + JumpHeight);

        if(onGround)
        {

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            {
                if (JumpHeight < maxJump)
                {
                    increaseJumpHeight = true;
                }
            }

            if(JumpHeight>= maxJump)
            {
                JumpHeight = maxJump;
            }

            if (increaseJumpHeight)
            {
                JumpHeight += increaseJumpBy;
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(0f, JumpHeight, 0f);
                onGround = false;
                increaseJumpHeight = false;
                jumped = true;               
            }

            if (jumped)
            {
                JumpHeight = 0;
                jumped = false;
            }        
        }

        if (!onGround)
        {               
            Horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            horizontalmovement = new Vector3(Horizontal * horizontalSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + horizontalmovement + forwardMovement);
            Quaternion horRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, Horizontal * horizontalSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * verRotation /*horRotation*/);            
        }        
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        onGround = true;
    }
    void OnCollisionExit(Collision col)
    {
        onGround = false;
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Edit:  Removing the bool `jumped` and adding `JumpHeight = 0` to `if(!onGround)` seems to solve the problem

Comment: It's difficult to tell just from looking at the code. Could you also post some debug info? Like the values of `onGround`, `jumpHeight`, and `jumped` when the jump fails (and the working jump immediately before the failure for comparison).

Comment: I got a error while recording the `onGround` value (see above). I am not sure if that's the cause of the issue. I can't record the exact value of `onGround` due the fast pace nature of the game (see above).

Comment: Update: the error mentioned above doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: Update: Noticed that the `jumped` value always appears as false regardless if the jump fails or not. Is this the source of the issue? @KevLoughrey

Comment: If you've found a solution, you should post an answer to your own question and accept it (rather than editing the original question with the solution). (For example, I was reading your question again before I realized you solved your issue. Posting and accepting an answer would help avoid this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the bool `jumped` and adding `JumpHeight = 0` to `if(!onGround)` seems to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Your code for capturing input using `Input.GetKeyDown` should be called from `Update`, not `FixedUpdate`.

It's possible for input events to be missed if it happens between two `FixedUpdate` calls. `FixedUpdate` does not necessarily fire every frame. For example, 2 `Update` calls might fire consecutively before a `FixedUpdate` fires.

(Note that you should still use `FixedUpdate` when dealing with RigidBody, as you have done already.)

---

(For more information, see this [discussion on Unity Answers: "Is Input detection ok to do in fixedupdate?"](https://answers.unity.com/questions/743221/is-input-detection-ok-to-do-in-fixedupdate.html) or other similar questions here like this one: [Unity Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) is not working](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/158845/115296).)

Comment: I don't think that's the issue as I had the same issue with having all my code in update().

Comment: It's still an issue though! Best to fix it or it could cause problems down the line.

Comment: Should I call the input in update using booleans?

Comment: @user209835 yes I think so. While this wasn't the main issue with your code, you should still address it.